# Highlight table row with checkbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML table. Each row contains a checkbox followed by some text.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>Name2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need some help writing a script that will highlight (adding a class) the rows that have been checked and unchecking will remove that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpb8

```
    $(":checkbox").change(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("highlight", this.checked)
    })
```

Comment: Out of interest why use closest instead of parents?

Comment: Because CLosest finds the first one and then stop searching for others while parents goes till top of the document and if you have nested trs it will process toggleClass on all of them. so closest is faster and efficient & less chances of error.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#yourTableId input:checkbox").change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(":checked")) {
            $this.closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
        } else {
            $this.closest("tr").removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass('highlight')
})
```

Comment: Hiya bruv, small note `:)` make it `is(':checked')` since it should be highlighted when checked.

Comment: Or you can just add the class in the html for the checkbox that are checked by default. Unless he has dynamic elements, I would do that and keep the js smaller.

Comment: you can not use parents as if the the table is inside anther table it will highlight all row in the hierarchy. use closest instead. also cant just toggle without checking if its checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/328QV/

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Table input").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("highlight");
        } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u1esuvhz/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
        alert();
        if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass("checked");
        } else $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("checked");
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.checked {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

```
      $(document).on('click','tr',function(){
    if ($(this).css('background-color')=="rgb(143, 162, 225)") {

        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',false);

        $(this).css('background','#ffffff'); 
    } else{
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked',true);

        $(this).css('background','#8FA2E1'); `enter code here`
    }
});
```